# Dropdown lists in JavaScript don't work

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html-select

I'm developping a site based on MVC 4.  When I started developing, I used jQuery 1.7, then 1.8.  I have 2 dropdown lists on a page.  I want to update the second one using the value of the first one.  So I tried to use onChange().  I migrated to jQuery 1.9 due to the template but my code still doesn't work. Any suggestion s?

```
    @Html.DropDownList("CategoryList", "---Select Category ---")
    @Html.DropDownList( "SkillList" , "-- select Skill --")
    <script>
    $('#CategoryList').onChange(function() {
        var selectedCategory = $(this).val();
        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("Category")', { id: selectedCategory }, function (months) {
            var monthsSelect = $('#SkillList');
            skillSelect.empty();
            // other of code ...


        });
    } );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here... you set a variable named monthsSelect but then try to access a different variable name.  Do you need to set the skillSelect variable to point to the other list?  Or maybe this is a typo and you have the wrong variable name?

```
        var monthsSelect = $('#SkillList');
        skillSelect.empty();
```

Comment: Actually I can put an alert function even before code but I  never enter in my code anymore. I mean the events isn't handled.

Answer (score 0):

Several API have been removed/modified from jquery 1.9.0v. To know what are all the changes done in 1.9v refer [this](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/) link. You need to include jquery migration scripts your application to use those depreacted functions.

Refer the below links.

http://blog.jquery.com/2013/02/16/jquery-migrate-1-1-1-released/

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/